# Angular http handling json response in case of http error

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, httpclient

I can't solve this issue and online I can't find anything, I do a post call like so:

```
return this.http.post(url, body, { headers: ConnectFunctions.getHeader() }).pipe(
  map(result => {
    return result;
  }),
  catchError(ConnectFunctions.handleError(url, []))
);
}
```

this is the response I get from the server

```
{"status":500,"timestamp":"21-07-2020 03:51:17","message":"my custom message","details":"some details"}
```

I would like to get the variable message ("my custom message") but I'm not able.

```
public static handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
        console.log("Error use: " + `${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);
        console.log("Error statusText: " + error.statusText);
        return of(error as T);
    };
}
```

How can I do it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your map function doesn't make much sense. But ignoring that, *this is the response I get from the server* is that an actual HTTP 500 status code or does it just say tht in the body? What does *I'm not able [to]* mean? Do you ever subscribe to this observable?

Comment: It's the raw response data received from the server that I see from the Chrome's developer tools under the Network tab.

Comment: that doesn't answer any of my questions. Please show us a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways to catch the error, but you can summarize it:

```
return this.http.post(url, body, { headers: ConnectFunctions.getHeader() })
      .catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    // simple logging, but you can do a lot more,
    console.error(err.error.message);
  });
```

See more about HttpErrorResponse: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse

Comment: this is the right answer. thank you. I am sorry Liam if I were not able to explain myself better but this answer saved my day.